# Take camera image and add to slider in android

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

I'm new to android and I'm trying to add **images** taken from the **camera** and add them to a `ViewPager`. It's supposed to look like a **image carousel**. This is what I've tried so far, but the problem is the same image is being added 5 times.
I want to know what can I change in the `getCount()` method of my `CustomAdapter` in order to get different images to the carousel.

**My MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public final static int CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE = 1034;
public String photoFileName = "photo.jpg";
public final String APP_TAG = "MyCustomApp";
ViewPager viewPager;
CustomSwipeAdapter adapter;

ImageView iv; 

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

  Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
  viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager); 

  btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, getPhotoFileUri(photoFileName));

            if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
                startActivityForResult(intent, CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);
            }

        }
    });

}

 //ON ACTIVITY RESULT..

 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {if (requestCode == CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {


            Uri takenPhotoUri = getPhotoFileUri(photoFileName);
            Bitmap takenImage = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(takenPhotoUri.getPath());


            adapter = new CustomSwipeAdapter(this, iv, takenImage);
            viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Picture Wasn't taken!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}


public Uri getPhotoFileUri(String fileName) {
    if (isExternalStorageAvailable()) {
        File mediaStoreDir = new File(getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), APP_TAG);

        if (!mediaStoreDir.exists() && !mediaStoreDir.mkdirs()) {
            Log.d(APP_TAG, "Failed to create Directory");
        }
        return Uri.fromFile(new File(mediaStoreDir.getPath() + File.separator + fileName));

    }
    return null;
}

private boolean isExternalStorageAvailable() {
    String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
    return state.equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED);
}
```

**CUSTOM ADAPTER**

```
public class CustomSwipeAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
private Context ctx;
private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
ImageView iv;
Bitmap imageTaken;


public CustomSwipeAdapter(Context ctx, ImageView iv, Bitmap imageTaken) {
    this.ctx = ctx;
    this.iv = iv;
    this.imageTaken = imageTaken;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 5;  //Need to get Image Count here...
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {

    return (view == (LinearLayout) object);
}

@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
    layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)      ctx.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View item_view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.swipe_layout, container, false);
    TextView tv = (TextView) item_view.findViewById(R.id.image_count);
    iv = (ImageView) item_view.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    iv.setImageBitmap(imageTaken);
    tv.setText("Image" + position);
    container.addView(item_view);
    return item_view;
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {

    container.removeView((LinearLayout) object);
  }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id ="@+id/view_pager"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Take a Photo"></Button>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**swipe_layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/image_count"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Hello World"
        android:textSize="25dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are seeing one image 5 times because you are supplying only one bitmap to the  adapter constructor and showing that image. 
 Please add new image taken from the camera to `ArrayList<Bitmap> bitMapList`  and pass that bitmap to the adapter.

And in getView Method take bitmap from the arralist and show in the carousel.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks! That worked well ! Never thought of adding the images to the ArrayList<Bitmap>. But i've fixed it now. :)

Comment: Thanks for accepting this answer, i am not sure who has upvote your question lolz :).